# Disable '\C-x\C-s" in multi-term mode

Tags: emacs, elisp

There is no need to use <kbd>C-x C-s</kbd> to `save buffer` in term mode. So I want to disable it. I tried to define a new binding in term mode to replace it, but failed.

```
(add-hook 'term-mode-hook 
          #'(lambda () 
              (define-key term-mode-map "\C-x\C-s"
                #'(lambda () 
                    (interactive)
                    (message "NO!")))))
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Update: I use multi-term which based on term mode.

Comment: Why are trying to save the buffer if there is no need to save it? Are you trying to Idiot-proof yourself?

Comment: @Raghu It is just a kind of habit when I edit files. In term mode, happen to press C-x C-s sometimes.

Comment: I think the name of the keymap in terminal mode is `terminal-map`, not `term-mode-map` (but it could be because I'm using an old version of Emacs).

Comment: @Barmar no `terminal-map` define...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As wvxvw said, I tried this and it works. Add below to `term-bind-key-alist`. Thanks everyone.

```
("\C-x\C-s" . (lambda () 
            (interactive)
            (message "NO!")))
```

Answer (score 1):

<del>Take off the #' from your code.</del>  It should work. But you will still be able to save the buffer with "M-x save-buffer"

UPDATE:

This code is working for me

```lisp
(add-hook 'term-mode-hook                                 
          (lambda ()                                           
              (define-key term-mode-map (kbd "C-x C-s")
                (lambda ()                                     
                    (interactive)                         
                    (message "hello world")))))
```

You will need to reload your term buffer after you setup the hook. It will not work for existing buffers

Comment: Weird, Do not work. Maybe it is becuase I use multi-term which based on term?

Comment: Raghu: `(lambda)` has long been equivalent to `#'(lambda)`, so although there's no need to use the `#'` quoting syntax, it shouldn't be the cause of any problem.

Comment: phils You are right presence/absence of #' should not make any difference in case of a lambda. Updated the answer....